# OpenCV optimisation

Tags: opencv, optimization, calibration

I am trying to understand how to calibrate a pinhole camera in a similar fashion to OpenCV (without OpenCV).

Whilst initializing the camera parameters based on Zhang method is fine, optimising them is another story.

Calibration in OpenCV happens at this line.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/eefee8574ab26be0bc102938f9f74e5c09829e77/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L1380

The code is barely commented. Any chance someone can explain me the different step of optimization of this function. I recognise at least 3 Jacobian matrix but it is not explicit what each does and how they are built.

Comment: you'll need to get a book on the topic. hartley n zisserman, forsyth n ponce, szeliski. those are commonly named. there are others. there are even online courses but don't trust online courses that aren't from decent universities, and even then you might be dissatisfied by the lack of didactic skill (high flying academics don't have to be good at teaching, they teach by forced osmosis).